# Display All Values in Local Option Set (picklist) Despite Records Per Page Limitation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a local option set (picklist) that is populated from a "Query CRM Data" query. The query returns all users. Currently, the number of users is greater than the records per page (set to 50), so only the first 50 users are displayed in the option set. I cannot change the default number of records per page as this would cause a big performance hit in the system.

Is there a way for me to be able to display all records in an option set (picklist) where the number of records is greater than the records per page setting? I need to be able to select multiple users at once, so I think that rules out the Lookup.

Any thoughts? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are talking about prompt and response in dialogs, don't you? I might be missing something, but can you select more then one option in picklist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention "Query CRM Data" so I take it you're creating a Dialog. Unfortunately the answer is no, you can't exceed the 50 limit of option sets on a dialog. You can only go beyond this limit when you have control over the query execution (such as in javascript or C#).

So in short, you'll have to use lookups. And also, as MarioZG mentions, you can only select 1 option in a option set/picklist anyway, so a picklist doesn't solve your other problem.

Comment: Ah for some reason I had thought you could select multiple in a picklist. I'm sure there's a way to do that with some javascript but seeing as it isn't part of my requirements, I think I can go with the lookup! So for that I just have to create a relationship to the User entity on the field I'd like to use, correct?

Comment: There's 2 ways to do it. Either create a relationship between the entities, or go to "Fields" on the target entity and add a new lookup field to point at the users entity. Both achieve the same thing